# What is the private keys and wallet

Tags: wallets, private-key

```json
{
  "type": "private-key",
  "version": 3,
  "crypto": {
    "ciphertext": "513b4f7565bc1d655bc1789f486f66c812e5af97a0b297167f083567c913f488",
    "cipherparams": {
      "iv": "dc6eaafcc462d7122aaeb2b16f3356e3"
    },
    "kdf": "scrypt",
    "kdfparams": {
      "r": 8,
      "p": 6,
      "n": 4096,
      "dklen": 32,
      "salt": "dbb74696f2f99e941d04619581a924b63d19d0a8064b94c536ba66fb71b2cb8e"
    },
    "mac": "f43c0efcbb44d067858c99c7336c9063ddc311ee2fc541c19e042f6b6d0d3027",
    "cipher": "aes-128-ctr"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/231381/can-i-find-a-private-key-for-a-known-encrypted-file

Comment: Hi ShugarYum! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! It seems to be a wallet v3 format.